# how to download multiple files from one server and upload to another concurrently in microservice architecture (concurrent piping)

Tags: scala, io, jvm, pipe, scale

I'm writing a (scala/jvm) microservice that is part of a CI solution.
Its job is to download built artifacts from some external build tool on the cloud and upload them to repositories from which they can be consumed, such as a docker registry or maven style repositories like Nexus.

There are many many such files for each build and many many such builds all the times, so the problem to solve is that of scale.

My microservice is integrated with an event queue (kafka), so it's easy to asynchronously assign tasks to workers.

I'm looking for the best way to manage my resources: nodes of cluster, threads, io, memory, storage - to handle the download and upload of all files, preferably without storing the entire content of each file locally on a file or in memory, but just to pipe from the source server to the target server.

I'm not sure what's the best approach to actually write the pipe code itself or how to best use the workers.

I was thinking of dispatching an event per file-to-pipe, and in each worker to pipe that one file by performing a get operation on the input server, a post operation on the target server and creating an in memory pipe between the streams with some buffer. 
In this scenario there could be different transfer speeds for the input and target servers and i'm not sure if that's a problem or not. I think this should be solved by TCP/IP at the OS level and nothing for me to handle applicatively. I think if i use different thread pools for the download client and the upload client i can expect decent usage of non-blocking io to perform the pipe.

Alternatively i can do something else entirely and do some sort of producer/consumer where some workers download files while others upload them? this means more storage and shared storage at that, and a custom configuration for this microservice, which i'm not excited about.

Any other suggestions/insights are also welcome.
The eventual solution should (hopefully) be robust, scalable and as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Are you positive the source cloud service is not going to offer an "export file to Nexus" solution in the near/medium future? If so maybe your solution does not have to be fully efficient.

I would look at FS2 for this job https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2/blob/series/1.0/README.md#example